# Member 'Storyboard.SetTargetName(DependencyObject, string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a startup animation for my WPF Application. And I get the following message:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNw9c.png)

And this is my current code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CQSo.png)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use code like this

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(startupAnimation1da, loadingWindow.Name);
```

Instead of

```
startupAnimation1.SetTargetName(startupAnimation1da, loadingWindow.Name);
```

---

Also, I don't think your code will run correctly, I think it will not do the animation. Because you created the `DoubleAnimation`, but did not set the target property that it needs to change. You can use `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty()` method to set it like this:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ANIMATION, PROPERTY);
```

And an example:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Button.WidthProperty));
```

---

Here is an example below of use `Storyboard.SetTargetName()` and `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty()` methods.

It is an animation of change button width.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Button x:Name="AnimationButton" Height="34" Width="100" Content="Begin" Click="AnimationButton_Click"></Button>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfTestApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AnimationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Create the animaton
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

            DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = 100,
                To = 300,
                Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)),
                AutoReverse = true,
                RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
            };

            storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);

            //Set taeget name
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(doubleAnimation, "AnimationButton");

            //Set target property
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Button.WidthProperty));

            //Begin the animaton
            storyboard.Begin(AnimationButton);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @HankStudios, You can try the code `Storyboard.SetTargetName(startupAnimation1da, loadingWindow.Name);`, is that work?